# Set Child View Controller Properties

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uilabel

Ok, I know this has been asked before and I have tried many different methods to make this work but for some reason it won't. I am trying to save a string to a label's text property. The label is in a child view controller called `tableVC` within a container view and I am setting it from the parentViewController, `ViewController` in an IBAction when the value of a UIDatePicker, `datePicker` is changed. I have tried:

```
tableVC *tVC = [[tableVC alloc] init];
tVC.timeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
```

and have also tried making a property `@property (strong, nonatomic) tableVC *tVC;` then doing:

```
_tVC = [tableVC alloc] init];
_tVC.timeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
```

but that doesn't work either. BTW, I have `#import "tableVC"`. I don't want a complicated delegate or protocol way of doing it as I'm thinking I am just making a noob mistake. Also, I have confirmed that `[formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]` does return the proper, non nil, formatted, value from the datePicker, using `NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date]);`.

**Edit**

Here is a little more information along with the entire files. The table is a static table defined in Storyboard. I thought this could be the cause of the problem but even when I substituted out the `tableVC` for a subclassed `UIViewController` with only one label it did not work. I think the problem lies in how I set the child view controller properties. However, I do not have this problem when using the `prepareForSeque` method in other projects. I can set values for properties of the destination controller no problem but not values for properties of view controllers which are not the destination controller. I think these two problems coincide. All connections were made properly through Storyboard.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "tableVC.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

- (IBAction)changedDatePickerSelection:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableVC *tVC = [[tableVC alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:tVC];
    [tVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    NSLog(@"parent");
}

- (IBAction)changedDatePickerSelection:(id)sender
{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    tableVC *tVC = (tableVC *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject;
    tVC.timeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];

    _testLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];

    NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:_datePicker.date]);
    NSLog(@"%@", tVC.timeLabel.text);
}

@end
```

tableVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface tableVC : UITableViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;

@end
```

tableVC.m

```
#import "tableVC.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface tableVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleTextField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *onOffSwitch;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *saveButton;

- (IBAction)saveAlarm;

@end

@implementation tableVC

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;

    _timeLabel.text = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"%@", _timeLabel.text);
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)aTextField
{
    [aTextField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}

- (IBAction)saveAlarm
{
    // do something
}

@end
```

Also, here are my two images to show how the `testLabel` from the `ViewController` is updated when the `datePicker`'s selection is changed, but how the `timeLabel` from the `tableVC` was not. The first image is before the change of selection and the second is after. For clarification, the `timeLabel` is the label on the right side of the third cell and the `testLabel` is the one directly above the `datePicker`.

http://cl.ly/image/2Q301v0d2m00

http://cl.ly/image/0223183E1t2m

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what does your `timeLabel` property look like?

Comment: @mkral `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeLabel;
`

Comment: are you adding `tableVC` programmatically or with InterfaceBuilder? If you're using interface builder, are you connecting all your outlets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you only have one child view controller, you can do it like this:

```
tableVC *tVC = (tableVC *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject;
tVC.timeLabel.text = ....;
```

If you have more than one child, then you have to figure out which one is the one you want, and use objectAtIndex: instead of lastObject.

After edit: This is what I did. I added a couple of properties and moved some code into the viewDidLoad, because there's no need to alloc init a new formatter every time you change the date picker:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "TableVC.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDateFormatter *formatter;
@property (strong,nonatomic) TableVC *tVC;

- (IBAction)changedDatePickerSelection:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    self.formatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    self.formatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterShortStyle;
    self.formatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

    self.tVC = (TableVC *)self.childViewControllers.lastObject;
}

- (IBAction)changedDatePickerSelection:(id)sender {

    self.tVC.timeLabel.text = [self.formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
    _testLabel.text = [self.formatter stringFromDate:self.datePicker.date];
}
```

I didn't change anything in TableVC other than to capitalize the name (you really should capitalize your class names).

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. Please see my revised post for more information. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MusicMathTech, I think your problem is all that code you just posted. If you set this up in IB by adding container views, which then automatically gives you an embedded controller, you don't need any code to set up the child view controllers. The code where you alloc init tVC and then add it as a child view controller is not needed.

Comment: Ok, I tried commenting out the alloc init and `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController`. Then I commented out the `@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *containerView` and removed the outlet from the container view in Storyboard. I also changed the `tableVC *tVC = [[tableVC alloc] init];` line in `changedDatePickerSelection` to just `table *tVC;` This still doesn't work though. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @MusicMathTech, try leaving changeDatePickerSelection as it is in your post, and just delete the entire viewDidLoad method. Also in changeDatePickerSelection log self.childViewControllers to see what you get.

Comment: @MusicMathTech I made a test app, and did what I told you to do, and it works fine.

Comment: Yes, I tried watering down a new app and just keeping the one method and two labels and it did not work. I logged the child view controllers and it does see the controller connected to the container in Storyboard but it does not update the label in the child view controller. Do I need to do something before the @interface? I have `#import "ViewController"` and `#import "testViewController"`. `testViewController` is the child view controller in my watered down app and is comparable to the `tableVC` from the original post.

Comment: Thank you!!! That's what fixed it! Not exactly sure at the moment but I can deduce that later. You have no idea how helpful that was. Thanks for taking the time to help me work it out. I'll +1 it when I get the reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are doing alloc/init which is making a *new* instance of the view controller. You need a pointer to the existing instance that is already on screen, probably by using an outlet (if this is set up in interface builder).

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean. I am using storyboards.